# Which SSD type is optimal for TempDB on new SQL hardware?

Tags: sql-server

Looking to purchase new bare metal SQL cluster hardware and run tempdb off local node instead of SAN.

Dell classifies their SSDs as:

- read intensive
- write intensive
- mixed use

Which SSD type is optimal for TempDB hosted directly on each cluster node (R.I., W.I. or M.U.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those SSD are designed for this scenario: a load balancer that re-route the traffic and divide it into read and write

[image]

- **Write intensive** is for master server where a lot of write happens
- **Read intensive:** is for replica server where a lot of read happens
- **Mixed used** is for everything else

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, you really have to know your planned workload on the servers.

What will be the actual scripts/queries that are going to be run on primary / secondary servers ? What will be the business processes ? How they will use TempDB ?

Primary server may benefit from Write-intensive (a lot of DML operations on millions of rows in temp tables, but very few rows returned/read from as the result), but it is also possible that on Primary you load data into tempDB once and read it many times with subsequent statements in a query, so in that case it would benefit from Read-intensive SSD...

If you don't know planned workload, go with mixed, and nobody's hurt

Answer (score 2):

TempDb is write-heavy.  Often a temp table or a spool is written and then only read once.  What this means for the Dell options, I can't say.

Comment: Is write heavy when they write an hash table but then they are read heavy when they read that hash table.